# How were these Linux TCP default settings decided?

Tags: linux, tcp, history

I spent quite some time tracking down a problem in production recently, where a database server disappearing would cause a hang of up to 2 hours (long wait for a `poll()` call in the libpq client library) for a connected client. Digging into the problem, I realized that these kernel parameters should be adjusted way down in order for severed TCP connections to be noticed in a timely fashion:

`net.ipv4.tcp_keepalive_time = 7200
net.ipv4.tcp_keepalive_probes = 9
net.ipv4.tcp_keepalive_intvl = 75
net.ipv4.tcp_retries2 = 15`

The four values above are from an Ubuntu 12.04 machine, and it looks like these defaults are unchanged from current [Linux kernel defaults](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/v4.1/Documentation/networking/ip-sysctl.txt#L315).

These settings seem to be heavily biased towards keeping an existing connection open, and being extremely stingy with keepalive probes. AIUI, the default `tcp_keepalive_time` of 2 hours means when we're waiting for a response for a remote host, we will wait patiently for 2 hours before initiating a keepalive probe to verify our connection is still valid. And then, if the remote host does not respond to a keepalive probe, we retry those keepalive probes 9 times (`tcp_keepalive_probes`), spaced 75 seconds apart (`tcp_keepalive_intvl`), so that's an extra 11 minutes before we decide the connection is really dead.

This matches what I've seen in the field: for example, if I start a `psql` session connected to a remote PostgreSQL instance, with some query waiting on a response, e.g.

`SELECT pg_sleep(30);`

and then have the remote server die a horrible death (e.g. drop traffic to that machine), I see my psql session waiting for up to 2 hours and 11 minutes before it figures out its connection is dead. As you might imagine, these default settings cause serious problems for code which we have talking to a database during, say, a database failover event. Turning these knobs down has helped a lot! And I see that I'm [not alone](http://tldp.org/LDP/solrhe/Securing-Optimizing-Linux-RH-Edition-v1.3/chap6sec75.html) in recommending these defaults be adjusted.

So my questions are:

- How long have the defaults been like this?
- What was the original rationale for making these TCP settings the default?
- Do any Linux distros change these default values?

And any other history or perspective on the rationale for these settings would be appreciated.

Comment: Some relevant info here... http://tldp.org/HOWTO/TCP-Keepalive-HOWTO/usingkeepalive.html

Comment: Note that you can change the first three per-connection in client code with the socket options `TCP_KEEPIDLE`, `TCP_KEEPCNT`, and `TCP_KEEPINTVL`.

Comment: @wnoise actually [since Linux 2.6.37](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/tcp.7.html) it should also be possible to specify socket option `TCP_USER_TIMEOUT` as well, instead of setting `net.ipv4.tcp_retries2` system-wide. Of course many applications (such as PostgreSQL in my example here) don't support `TCP_USER_TIMEOUT` yet.

Comment: @JoshKupershmidt ... Postgres v13+ now supports tcp_user_timeout. Just FYI.

Comment: @Robins [so does 12](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/runtime-config-connection.html#GUC-TCP-USER-TIMEOUT)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[RFC 1122](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1122) specifies in section 4.2.3.6 that the keep-alive period must not default to less than two hours.

Comment: Nice, thank you for digging that up. I think that mostly answers the question of why `tcp_keepalive_time` defaults to 7200, though I'd still be interested in the precedent/explanation for the the other three relevant settings.

Comment: Removing My answer as this answers the question (at least for one of the values)

Comment: @coteyr Thanks anyway, I appreciate the effort. IIRC there was an intriguing comment on your answer suggesting that in earlier Linux kernels the default was 15 minutes. I'd be interested in how/why that got changed to 2 hours, or set to 15 minutes in the first place.